# SSL Certificates explanation

Tags: wordpress, ssl, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, bitnami

Can someone answer a simple SSL Cert question for me to derisk my decision?

My Stack: Bitami WordPress instance on GCP VM.

Situation

I have a website with an SSL cert linked to my domain name.
I started an instance with a new static IP address.
I remapped the domain name to the new servers and added the correct credentials [confirmed everything is configured correctly with the GCP team].
Ran -dig command and confirmed new instance is mapped to the domain name.

Problem

The domain name will not load in the browser. Get the "NET:: ERR_CERT_INVALID" message.

My Diagnosis

I haven't transferred my SSL to my new IP address.

Confusion

Everywhere I read says the SSL is mapped to the domain name, not the IP address itself. So theoretically there should not be an issue.

Question(s) to you

Do I solve this simply by generating new SSL cert on the new instance? Will that just overwrite the old SSL cert and map my domain name to the new SSL cert?

If not - what's the solution?

I don't understand the technical relationship between IP address, domain names, and certs. I have read as much as I can and everyone seems to talk around it but not explain it in detail.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using a google-managed SSL certificate or a self managed certificate?
Also when you go to your load balancer and check the certificate, what is the current status of it?

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami Engineer here,

If you created a new instance from scratch, you will need to migrate the SSL certificates from the first instance to the second one. You can either copy the SSL certificates from the machine or download them again from the CA website and substitute the files you have in the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf folder.

In case you were using a Let's Encrypt certificate, you can generate new certificates by using the Bitnami HTTPS configuration tool (/opt/bitnami/bncert-tool) or by running the CLI tool to generate new certificates. If you use the Bitnami HTTPS configuration tool, you won't need to modify the Apache's configuration, the tool will do that for you. You can learn more about it here

https://docs.bitnami.com/google/how-to/understand-bncert/

Please remember to confirm that the domain name is configured properly by checking your domain using this online tool before trying to generate the certificates

https://www.whatsmydns.net/

Comment: Awesome thanks man - I have scoured bitnami's documentation and this is the page I have been looking for! Appreciate the link!

Answer (score 0):

New problem.

I used the bncert tool as per Jotas recommendation and it worked well.

I checked my domain name via 'whatsmydns' as well as my SSL via an SSL checking tool. All worked out as expected - my IP address is matching against my Domain name and SSL is matching against my domain name.

I type my domain name into the browser and it loads my site with the padlock, across all browsers.

So from the outside - it looks like everything is fine.

But I have two issues still.

Problem #1:

In my WordPress 'general>settings', I tried to update my 'WordPress address' and 'site address' but they are greyed out. So I updated my `wp-config` file with the new https addresses as per these instructions which have worked for me before without issues (https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-change-your-wordpress-site-urls-step-by-step/). It didn't break the site, but I could no longer log in. As soon as I deleted the new wp-config code, I could log in again. So if that won't work, I now have no course of action to update my 'WordPress' and 'site' addresses.

**So my questions are** - do you know why this won't work? Is it a bitnami quirk? And does it matter? If the domain is working, does it matter if I keep the wp-config file as an http address and not an https address?

Problem #2:

My domain name takes me to my site at the correct IP address. It loads with a secure padlock icon. I can log in. Everything works as it should.

If I use the IP address, however, instead of the domain name, it also loads the same site but as an insecure site with no padlock.

**Question - Any idea how that is possible?** I thought a domain name was just a human-friendly version of an IP address. And if the webserver is a single server, how can using a domain name versus an IP address generate different front end results?

Thanks again team, as a person who is new to this community, it really does give you faith in humanity.

Comment: For "problem 1", what method did you follow? [Updating the WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME variables in the /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php file](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/wordpress/administration/configure-domain/) should be enough. Regarding the second problem, an IP is not a valid domain so the certificate doesn't match. In that case, you will need to force the redirection from the IP to the domain as you can see [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/administration/use-single-domain/)